# How to set that main effects should ALWAYS be included

Tags: r

I am using the `olsrr` package with the `ols_step_all_possible` function.
My model has 4 predictor variables: `Year`, `Lay_date`, `Clutch_size` and `Yolk_mass`.

My first model I define like this:

```
m1 <- lm(T4 ~ Year + Jul_date + Clutch_size + Yolk_mass, data=data)

k1 <- ols_step_all_possible(m1)
```

The output (`k1`) then gives me 15 possible models with different combinations of predictors. Fine. Now, I want to include two way interactions.

```
m2 <- lm(T4 ~ Year*Jul_date + Year*Clutch_size + Year*Yolk_mass, data=data)

k2 <- ols_step_all_possible(m2, iterm = TRUE)
```

Here is where I get stuck: The output `k2` generates 127 possible models (all possible). Some of them include interactions without including the main effect. For example, the model with the highest adjusted R-squared includes the following predictors:

`Jul_date`, `Clutch_size`, `Yolk_mass`, `Year:Yolk_mass`

The variable `Year` is the one I am mainly interested in. However, here it is only included as an interaction with yolk mass, not as a main effect (indicated by ":" instead of "*").

How do I choose the model of interest with the highest R-squared? Can I add a command that forces R to always disregard models that do not include `Year` as a main factor? Or should I simply search through the output `k2` and find the model that 1) includes `Year`, and 2) of those the one that has highest R-squared?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Cheers, Maggi

Comment: Can't you just include `Year` without interaction in the model? i.e. `m2 <- lm(T4 ~ Year  + Year*Jul_date + Year*Clutch_size + Year*Yolk_mass, data=data)`

Comment: Then again, the model with the highest adjiusted R2 contains the following predictors: _Jul_date Clutch_size Year:Yolk_mass_ So, year again only in an interaction

Comment: I have no experience using`ols_step_all_possible` but doesn't this run into the risk of [overfitting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/281449/what-exactly-is-overfitting) ? The solution with highest R2 is an artefact of your data? (You could overcome this for example using cross validation and/or maybe bootstrapping...)

Comment: Just a final observation/tip: I wouldn't focus so much on the R2 values! Especially with the increased risk of over fitting due to the multiple tests... just my 5 cents ;)
You may consider posting this question to the  aptly named statistics page [cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) of stackexchange.